# ([Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer)

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and to programming in general. I am trying to make this small code but when I want to use the if function I get this error.

I have no idea what it could be. I tried several conventions and none of them work.
I was hoping someone could give me advice on how to write this line of code better.
here is the thing

```
#include <iostream>
#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //variables
    char cod_ref[6];
    char des_prod[60];
    char disp;
    int size;
    int cost;
    int price;
    int num;
    //impresiones y asignación de variables
    cout<<"Digite el codigo de referencia del producto (5 digitos)" << endl;
    cin.getline(cod_ref, 6);
    cout<<"Digite la descripción del producto"<<endl;
    cin.getline(des_prod, 60);
    cout<<"Digite la talla del producto"<<endl;
    cin>>size;
    cout<<"Cantidad de productos"<<endl;
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"¿Disponible para la venta? S/N"<<endl;
    cin>>disp;
    cout<<"Digite el costo por unidad"<<endl;
    cin>>cost;
    cout<<"Digite el precio de venta por unidad"<<endl;
    cin>>price;

    //limpieza de pantalla
    system("cls");
    //impresión final
    cout<<"REFERENCIA: "<< cod_ref <<endl;
    cout<<"DESCRIPCIÓN: "<< des_prod  <<endl;
    cout<<"DISPONIBILIDAD: ";
    if( disp == "s"||"S" ){
        cout<<"Disponible";
    }else{
        cout<<"No Disponible";
    }
    cout<<"COSTO UNIDAD: "<< cost <<endl;
    cout<<"COSTO TOTAL: "<< cost * num <<endl;
    cout<<"PRECIO UNIDAD: "<< price <<endl;
    cout<<"PRECIO POR "<< num <<" UNIDADES: "<< price * num <<endl;
    cout<<"GANANCIA POR UNIDAD: "<< price - cost <<endl; 
    cout<<"GANANCIA TOTAL: " << (price * num) - (cost * num) <<endl;
    //cout<<"PORCENTAGE DE GANANCIA: "<<
    
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

here is where i get the error
   `if( disp == "s"||"S" ){`

Comment: A string such as “s” gets replaced by a pointer. The pointer is then tested for being nullptr, if it isn’t it’s equivalent to true and so the if is always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `if (disp == "s"||"S")` does not do what you think it does.

Due to the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) rules, the `==` operator has a higher precedence than the `||` operator, so the statement is processed AS-IF you had written it like this instead:

`if ( (disp == "s") || "S" )`

And in the case of the expression `disp == "s"`, `disp` is a single `char` that gets *promoted* to `int` in comparisons, and `"s"` is a string literal of type `const char[2]` which *decays* into a `const char*` pointer in this context.  Thus, the compiler complains, because comparing an integer to a pointer is not a valid operation.

Since `disp` is a `char`, you would need to use `'` instead of `"` in your comparison:

`if ( disp == 's' || "S" )`

That will at least get rid of the compiler error, but the code will still be logically wrong, because now the compiler will process it like this:

`if ( (disp == 's') || "S" )`

If `disp` equals `s` then the `if` evaluates as `true`, otherwise `"S"` is evaluated and can never decay into a null pointer, so it will always evaluate as `true`, thus your `if` will *ALWAYS* evaluate as `true` regardless of the value of `disp`.  Same thing if you were to change `"S"` into `'S'`:

`if ( (disp == 's') || 'S' )`

So, you might consider moving the parenthesis around the values instead, eg:

`if ( disp == ('s' || 'S') )`

And that would compile, but still be logically wrong, because the expression `'s' || 'S'` will *ALWAYS* evaluate as `true`, which converts to integer `1`, and so you would be comparing `disp` to `1`, which will *NEVER* evaluate as `true` for user input.

To do what you are attempting, you need a separate `==` comparison for each value you want to compare, eg:

`if ( (disp == 's') || (disp == 'S') )`

Answer (score 4):

Use single quotes for char character comparisons, double quotes implies a string which is technically a char * type.

ie.

```
if (disp == 's' || disp == 'S')
```

Comment: Good answer because it fixes both problems with that `if`, but I strongly recommend a quick edit to add a one-liner explaining why you split up `disp == "s"||"S"`.  I know why. Clearly you know why, but just as clearly, the asker doesn't.

Comment: "*a string ... is technically a char * type*" - that is incorrect. A **string literal** is a `const char[N]` array, where `N` is the length of the string +1 for the null terminator. An array *decays* into a pointer to its first element *in certain contexts*.